# How do you use multiple scripts in the same spreadsheet?

Tags: database, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that tracks legal cases from start to finish. In that spreadsheet I used a script to create dependent dropdown menus on multiple rows (I'll share the script at the end). The main dropdown menu tells me what Department the case is in. The Departments are Transcription; Doctor; Scheduling; Records; QA; and Billing.

I also have a script that is supposed to moves an entire row of data to a separate tab labeled Billing when the department dropdown menu is set to Billing. I had this script working before I made the dependent dropdown menus and was just using data validation to create my dropdown menu.

Both of these scripts work separately but when I try to use them together the dependent dropdown menus quit working and when the department is set to Billing that row disappears like its supposed to except it doesn't show up on the Billing tab like its supposed to. I have no idea where it goes.

Can someone please tell me how to get both scripts to work at the same time? And, why the row of data disappears when the department is set to Billing but doesn't go to the Billing tab?

**Dependent Dropdown Menu Script**

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database");
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("options");
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2,1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

function myFunction() {
 
  var list = ["a","b","c","f"];
  var cell = ws.getRange("J2");
  applyValidationToCell(list,cell);
  
}


function onEdit(event){
  var activeCell = event.range;
  var value = activeCell.getValue();
  var row = activeCell.getRow();
  var column = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "Database" && column === 5 && row > 1){

      if(value === ""){
        ws.getRange(row,10).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(row,10).clearValidations();
      } else{
      ws.getRange(row,10).clearContent();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(options){ return options[0] === value });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(options){ return options[1] });
      Logger.log(listToApply);
      var cell = ws.getRange(row,10);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
      }
  }
}


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();
  
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

**Billing Script**

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database");
var wsOptions = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("options");
var options = wsOptions.getRange(2, 1,wsOptions.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

function myFunction() {

var list = ["a","b","g"];
var cell = ws.getRange("K2");
applyValidationToCell(list,cell);

}

function onEdit(e){
 var activeCell = e.range;
 var val = activeCell.getValue();
 var r = activeCell.getRow();
 var c = activeCell.getColumn();
 var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
 if(wsName == "Database" && c === 5 && r > 1){
   var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){return o[0] === val});
   var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){ return o[1]});
   console.log(listToApply);
   var cell = ws.getRange(r, 10);
   applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
 }
}



function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

var rule = SpreadsheetApp
.newDataValidation()
.requireValueInList(list)
.setAllowInvalid(false)
.build();

cell.setDataValidation(rule);  
}

function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  if (r.columnStart != 5|| r.rowStart == 2 || e.value == src.getName()) return;
  const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(e.value);
  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,30).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,30));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to walk through all of your code, but why not just push them all into one procedure? Or break them up into small routine, and have some other procedure call them all in sequence?

Comment: Do you have any experience coding or is this all a copy/paste job from somewhere?

Comment: No experience. I got the codes from watching YouTube tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

All functions have to have a unique name and all functions have access to all sheets.  onedit triggers are generated on every user edit and it's up to the onEdit function to route edits from the appropriate sheets using information gathered from the event object.  Note: Sheet Name = e.range.getSheet().getName() where e is populated by the event object in the function declaration function onEdit(e) {}

The if statement below limits access to edits that occur on Sheet name "Database" and e.range.columnStart == 5 and rows greater than one

```
 if(wsName == "Database" && column === 5 && row > 1){

      if(value === ""){
        ws.getRange(row,10).clearContent();
        ws.getRange(row,10).clearValidations();
      } else{
      ws.getRange(row,10).clearContent();
      var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(options){ return options[0] === value });
      var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(options){ return options[1] });
      Logger.log(listToApply);
      var cell = ws.getRange(row,10);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
      }
  }
```

if you require actions from other sheets then you must add more if statements or other conditional logic to route the appropriate edit traffic to the the correct processing statements.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more. I have no experience with this stuff but am trying to figure it out for work. 
The spreadsheet I'm working with has 3 sheets; the main on in labeled Database and it houses info on all the cases we are currently working on. The next sheet is the Billing tab, which is pretty self-explanatory. Then the last sheet is Options, which is where my dependent dropdown menus pull their info from.

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Column 5 is where the Department drop down menu is on the the Database sheet. I want the code to move the entire row of data over to the Billing sheet when someone selects Billing as the department. The code removes the row from the Database sheet but but I don't know where it goes. How do I make the row appear on the Billing sheet?

Comment: you can use copyTo() or setValues() which are both in Class Range

Comment: I'm not sure how to use those. Is there a way for me to upload or share a copy of my spreadsheet? It seems like it would make this easier.

Comment: The problem with making to easy is that you end up not learning how to navigate the documenation to find the functions you require and you don't have to learn how to read the documentation  to figure out what kind of parameters you need and what kind of object the function returns.  And so you may end up not ever learning how to program.  If you want to learn how to program then you must learn to write your own programs by trying to write your own programs.  If you don't wish to learn how to write programs then this isn't the site for you.

Comment: Okay, then you said all functions have to have a unique name. So, how do I use multiple onEdit functions that do different things?

Comment: By combining all of the functions in to one onEdit() function and you must also keep in mind that onEdit(e) functions that use a simple trigger must complete in 30 seconds.  I think the basic idea here is that an onEdit() function should be kept short. It's not meant to do everything.  In my own programming I hardly ever use them